# getScript new javascript files when load content from another file via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am loading content from another url using ajax. Problem is I need all the new javascript files from that html page. Please help

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'another.html',
    dataType: "html",
    method: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      var result = $('<div></div>').append(data).find('#inside');
      $('#target').find('#inside').html(result.html()));
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    alert(err);
  }
});
```

Note: This is same domain.

This function load content perfectly but just does not load the new javascript files from another.html as expected. I need those javascript file too. I can use getScript function to include but need the source of the files which is not available in current document.

Comment: show what and how you are trying now?

Comment: Other domain, forget it

Comment: It is within same domain.